# Passing Mapped Data To A Material-UI Modal

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to pass a list of values to buttons. On Clicking the buttons a modal with the specifically mapped value should appear but in my case only the last value **(3)** in my array appears in all modals...
How should I fix it ?

```
  state = {
    open: false,
    stationData : [
      { id:1, number:'1' },
      { id:2, number:'2' },
      { id:3, number:'3' }
    ],
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const {stationData} = this.state;
    {stationData.map((station,index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={styles.button} onClick={this.handleOpen}>
                {station.number}
            </Button>
            <Modal 
                open={this.state.open} 
                onClose={this.handleClose} 
                aria-labelledby={index} 
                aria-describedby={index}
            >
                <div style={styles.modal}>
                    {station.number}
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    ))}
  }
```

check out on this code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwnyq7zxpq)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are creating three different modals in your `stationData.map()` function and each one of them depend on a single state `this.state.open`. So whenever a button is pressed all three of them is getting opened and you are seeing the last one on top. So 3 is always visible.

What you should do is- create only one modal and keep track of which button is pressed in a new state `this.state.stationNumber`. That way, the only modal will fire and it will know what to render from the state.

Here is your modified code, I have added comments where necessary:

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    stationNumber: null,
    stationData: [
      { id: 1, number: "1" },
      { id: 2, number: "2" },
      { id: 3, number: "3" }
    ]
  };

  handleOpen = stationNumber => () => {
    // get which button was pressed via `stationNumber`
    // open the modal and set the `stationNumber` state to that argument
    this.setState({ open: true, stationNumber: stationNumber });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
  render() {
    const { stationData } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={styles.wrapper}>
        <div style={styles.body}>
          <Paper square elevation={0} style={styles.container}>
            {stationData.map((station, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  style={styles.button}
                  // pass which button was clicked as an argument
                  onClick={this.handleOpen(station.number)}
                >
                  {station.number}
                </Button>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Paper>

          {/* add only one modal */}
          <Modal open={this.state.open} onClose={this.handleClose}>
            {/* display the content based on newly set state */}
            <div style={styles.modal}>{this.state.stationNumber}</div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Material UI Playground]

Comment: Thanks...It works... How would I pass the stationData state instead of the number?

Comment: You would send the entire `station` to `handleOpen`, instead of `station.number`. But it is usually done by sending the id instead of the whole object. Because if the modal knows the id then it can read the related object from the array.

Comment: Also consider moving the stationData array out of the state and assign to a const if they are don't change during rendering.

Comment: Thanks....Since I'll be connecting to a firebase backend I find storing in the state would be easier due to mutation

Comment: I know I'm nearly two years after the event, but thanks @mehamasum! You saved me hours...